# Next/Prev posts on same page

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, next

Hello WordPress Users,

I'm stuck with a problem building my wordpress website and I can't figure out what to do about it.

Currently I'm showing 2 posts form the category 'News' at the page 'News'. At the bottom of this page I want a Prev/Next button that shows the next or previous 2 posts from the same category.

So I was searching how I coud do that.
So I found this code:

```
previous_posts_link('Newer Entries »')
next_posts_link('« Older Entries');
```

This displays a link like I was expecting.
But both links are not working (page reload, but same entry's shown).

I also found this [in this codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Next_and_Previous_Links):

```
posts_nav_link('∞','Go Forward In Time','Go Back in Time');
```

Also at 'Setting' > 'Reading' I had set max posts to 2.

I don't know how I can handle this.
Is there a way to show the next 2 (or 'X') posts from the same categorie when a button 'Next' or 'Prev' is pressed?

Thanks!

Edit:
This is how I get the posts:

```
$args_news= array(
        'cat' => 1,
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'DESC'
    );

    query_posts( $args_news );

    if ( have_posts() ) :
        while ( have_posts() ) :
            the_post();

          the_title();
          the_content();

          endwhile;
    endif;
```

But still no idea how I can make pages of this posts. 
Currenty it's displaying the last 2 posts..

Comment: Please put your code in question then we can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `Paged` into parameter array of `query_posts`

You should set `get_query_var( 'paged' );` if you want your query to work with pagination.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args_news= array(
        'cat' => 1,
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'paged' => $paged,
    );

    query_posts( $args_news );
if ( have_posts() ) :
        while ( have_posts() ) :
            the_post();

          the_title();
          the_content();

          endwhile;
    endif;
```

for more information:https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination

Comment: +1 for being faster. ;) You still have to add `max_num_pages` to the links (at least the _next_ link) in order to get them work properly.

Answer (score 1):

You both have to use the `paged` query var for the loop, and the `max_num_pages` var for the links:

```
$news_args = array(
    'cat' => 1,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
);

$news_query = new WP_Query($news_args);

if ($news_query->have_posts()) :

    while ($news_query->have_posts()) : $news_query->the_post();
        the_title();
        the_content();
    endwhile;

    previous_posts_link('prev', $news_query->max_num_pages);
    echo ' &mdash; ';
    next_posts_link('next', $news_query->max_num_pages);

endif;
```